# Building indoor water feature / water fountain

Tags: water

I would like to have my own little waterfall inside my house.  I find the flowing water very soothing and relaxing.

I have seen a couple of "desktop" water fountains, and that is the rough idea, now I just want to scale that up several notches.

The size I would like to go for is probably about 1m cube (so 1 meter wide by 1 meter tall by a meter deep)

What do I need, where do I start?  I thought as a good starting point is to get a nice photo of a real life waterfall and try to build that?

Comment: Have you looked into water walls? They are really nice but a bit expensive but the photos could give you some good ideas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've built something similar for outdoor use, but it could just as easily have been an indoor fountain. The easiest way to construct it is from pottery, preferably something non-porous.

If you go to a Garden Ridge or big box hardware store you should be able to find a good selection of pots, and it usually works out well to buy multiple sizes of the exact same style of pot so you can layer them. It is best if the largest/bottom pot doesn't have a drain hole on it. The more "falls" you have in the fountain, the more you will get that nice waterfall sound.

You will also, of course, need to get a fountain pump (also available at the HW store), and some decorative rocks to fill each of the pots. I really like the black smooth river-stone type.

You could probably also create a pretty cool effect by adding a rain chain to the design.

[image: Rain Chain]

Answer (score 2):

The basics you'll need are a watertight container to receive the water, a pump and something for the water to fall out of.

There might be an "outdoor" water feature that you could use. If it doesn't come with a suitable base you'll have to find something to sit it in.

Comment: A related option would be to use the pump/tubing from an existing unit, and to build your own vessels. My only advice would be to try to keep the spray down to avoid causing indoor water damage, and to avoid any possibility of stagnant water!